# Stopping a looped CAAnimation after current cycle has finished

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

In my application, I have some CAAnimations which loop infinitely (`animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF`).

What I want to do is remove those animations, after the current cycle has finished. `-[CALayer removeAnimationForKey:]` makes the layer jump to it's normal position, which I want to prevent.

What i *could* do is: get the current transform of the layers presentation layer (i'm doing a rotation), calculate the time to finish the animation, remove the animation, and add another animation with a repeatCount of one, but that seems unnecessary complicated and i feel there must be a more simple way to do this.

So, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using an animation whose completion block invokes the animation again, based on a flag? When you want to make the animation sequence stop, set the flag to false. The completion block will see that the repeat flag is false, and stop at the end of the last cycle.

After committing your animation, you should change the transform to its end value. If you're doing view animation, just set the transform to its final value. That way, once the animation is removed, it will stay at the end state.

If you're using layer transforms, you'll need to put the code that sets the transform to its final state in a CATransactionBegin/ with [CATransaction setDisableActions: YES], so that change is not implicitly animated.

Comment: Using implicit animations .. i had not thought of that, but i think that would also require some hackery, since i will have several views with this animation, and need to start/stop those individually .. i will see if i can get anywhere with implicit animations tomorrow anyway

Answer (score -1):

Using the same property you were using to set the number of repeats, you can get the desired behaviour you're after. This will end the animation after the cycle finishes.

```
animation.repeatCount = 0
```

Comment: This does not work because the Docs state that `...you must not modify any properties of the returned [CAAnimation] object. Doing so will result in undefined behavior.`

Comment: I don’t know what part of the docs you’re looking at, but I don’t think it applies here. Your quote is even saying ‘don’t modify the CAAnimation Array object’. Where is this array coming from?